# Ngx-translate not translating anything

Tags: angular, internationalization, ngx-translate

I am in the process of internationalizing my current Angular 12 prototype application. *Prototype* means there is only the skeleton and a bunch of administrative features, and the developer(s) are in the process of coding vertical features in their working branch.

I have done the following, mostly following [this tutorial](https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit/tutorials/how-to-translate-your-angular-app-with-ngx-translate)

- Added the required dependencies in `package.json`

  ```json
  "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
  "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
  ```

  and devDependencies:

  ```json
  "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract": "^7.0.4",
  ```
- Set up AppModule (that's `SharedModule` in my case).

  The module is imported by `AppModule` anyway:

  ```js
  import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
  import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
  import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
  import {DelayInterceptor} from "./interceptors/delay.interceptor";
  import {ConfirmationDialogComponent} from './dialogs/confirmation-dialog/confirmation-dialog.component';
  import {MaterialModule} from "./material.module";
  import {GenericErrorDisplayComponent} from './error/generic-error-display/generic-error-display.component';
  import {TranslateLoader, TranslateModule} from "@ngx-translate/core";
  import {TranslateHttpLoader} from "@ngx-translate/http-loader";


  @NgModule({
    declarations: [
      ConfirmationDialogComponent,
      GenericErrorDisplayComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      CommonModule,
      MaterialModule,
      TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
          deps: [HttpClient]
        }
      })
    ],
    providers: [
      {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: DelayInterceptor,
        multi: true
      },
    ],
    exports: [
      MaterialModule,
    ]
  })
  export class SharedModule {
  }

  // required for AOT compilation
  export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient): TranslateHttpLoader {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
  }
  ```
- Set up some translation strings.

  In some of my HTML files, I added `translate` directive, e.g.

  ```html
  <button (click)=add() class="btn btn-success" id="btn-add" mat-button translate>Aggiungi Ruoli</button>
  ```
- Ran `ngx-translate-extract`

  ```json
  "i18n:init": "ngx-translate-extract --input ./src --output ./src/assets/i18n/template.json --key-as-default-value --replace --format json",
  "i18n:extract": "ngx-translate-extract --input ./src --output ./src/assets/i18n/it.json --output ./src/assets/i18n/en.json --clean --format json",
  ```

  `ngx-translate-extract` populated some JSON files I had to amend

  en.json

  ```json
  {
      "Permission": "Permission",
      "LegalEntity": "Legal Entity",
      "AML Type": "AML Type",
      "Indietro": "Back",
      "Salva": "Save",
      "Aggiungi Ruoli": "Add Roles",
      "ID": "ID",
      "Nome": "Name",
      "Data Creazione": "Created Date",
      "Data Modifica": "Modified Date",
      "Azioni": "Actions",
      "Aggiorna": "Refresh",
      "Nessun risultato trovato": "No result found",
      "Necessario eseguire login all'applicazione": "Application login is required"
  }
  ```

  Yes, that's a bunch of strings for now
- Set default language.

  Now I have set `en` as default language. In the `AppComponent`:

  ```js
    constructor(
      private router: Router,
      private injector: Injector,
      private translate: TranslateService,
    ) {
       translate.setDefaultLang(environment.language); //this is equal to 'en'
    }
  ```

Running the application, I expected text to appear in English, but was still localized. I have checked the Network tab and, indeed, the English JSON file is loaded

But none of the stings is localized in English

[image: Localized page]

The console shows no error.

What is wrong in this setup and what should I do next to display English text?

By using `ngx-translate-extract`, I am now using the third approach provided by the tutorial:

> - translation directive — id as a child `<element translate>id</element>`

so everything should work fine.

Following the GitHub tutorial, I moved the `TranslationModule.forRoot` import from the SharedModule to the AppModule. Same result as before.

Comment: replace this line `translate.setDefaultLang(environment.language);` to this `translate.setDefaultLang('en-US');` and see now is it now english text translation coming up or not ?

Comment: If I change the value of the environment constant, the network shows a 404 error for the file `en-US.json` which obviously does not exist. I assume `'en-US'` quoted string literal, because the method accepts a string. Or did you mean some kind of `en-US` unquoted Typescript variable/object?

Comment: Then, will you add `translate.setDefaultLang('en')` and see if it's working or not? Or make small demo of your code using stackbliz and share it here.

Answer (score 1):

I fell into this trap, too, but finally figured it out.

A lot of angular elements create wrapper elements, so for example a:

```
<button translate>My message</button>
```

actually turns into

```
<button><span class="mat-button-wrapper">My message</span></button>
```

in which case the translation attribute lands on the wrong element.

I ended up having to do:

```
<button><span translate>My message</span></button>
```

to work around it.